# Retrieving an image from mongoengine and display it on a page as http reponse in python

Tags: python, cherrypy, gridfs, mongoengine, render-to-response

Hello am new with mongoengine. I just want to retrieving an image from mongoengine and display it on a page as http reponse in python. I have added images to database and i printed it in the console and i got the following result:

```
 <GridFSProxy: 506038485e160077b3efc592>
 genus:m
 family:n
 <GridFSProxy: 5060384a5e160077b3efc595>
 genus:m
 family:n
```

this is my output when i printed the contents in database.from this i understood that the image got saved into database as objects with ids and now what i want is to display these images into a web page. I use for example`open(os.path.join(MEDIA_DIR, u"users/clients.html"))` to open a  client page. how can i show the image in the client page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taking the [documentation example](http://docs.mongoengine.org/en/latest/guide/gridfs.html?highlight=gridfs#retrieval) you can retrieve a file like so:

```
marmot = Animal.objects(genus='Marmota').first()
photo = marmot.photo.read()
content_type = marmot.photo.content_type
```

So you can get the content_type and set the headers correctly and yield the photo as the content

Comment: `photo` has the image file which you can stream.
`content_type` has the content type so you set headers with it.

Comment: ross i got the image file path in my console but i want it to get displayed on an html page can u help me with that?